# How to create authorization URL request with paramters

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, httprequest, yahoo-api

im trying to work with yahoo Gemini api
which need first to implement using Ouath 2.0

going into this [link](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/flows_implicitgrant/)

Its saying i need to create a request to a URL with "Request Parameters"

```
client_id
redirect_uri
```

now lets say i do it in java:

this is my HTTP request:

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httppost = new 
HttpPost("https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth");
```

is this how i added paramters to the request ?

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "ABCDEFGH"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "http://www.goTo.Com"));
```

is this is how i execute the entire request ?

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

1. is this the currect way to Get an authorization URL and authorize access ?
2. is there any other way / simpler doing that ?
3. what should i expect in the response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe that when you're working with Yahoo Gemini, you have to use a specific couple of *consumer_key/consumer_secret* according to my little investigation as stated in this [issue](https://github.com/josuebrunel/yahoo-oauth/issues/43)

You check the [guide](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/) out for an implementation of **oauth2** for yahoo apis.
Hope it helped